# Hotpoint Dish Washer Not Draining

Tags: dishwasher

The model is AQUARIUS FDW60. For about a month it was leaving bits of food all over the dishes and then one day, it just wouldn't drain and now it won't work at all...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

first, remove the drain hose. it's usually a flexible hose connected to he drain pipe under your sink. be careful, because when you remove it, it may spill a bunch of nasty water from both the hose and the bottom of the dishwasher.

clean out the hose, or replace it if it looks crushed or damaged at all.

every dishwasher has a one-way valve to prevent the water it pumps out from returning to the dish washer. sometimes the valve is built in to the hose, and sometimes it's built in to the dishwasher. find your valve and make sure it's clean and not jammed. if it looks broken, you can get it replaced.

if the valve looks ok, put everything back together and test it out.

if it still doesn't work, you may need to replace the pump, which should also be fairly easy to replace and available online.